# weird Logcat output when dismissing custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am have a custom keyboard app, and I get this LogCat output about 1/4 of the time when I press the back button to get out of it:

```
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361): IME died: com.mypackage/.MyActivity dropping: KeyEvent{action=1 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=72}
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361): android.os.DeadObjectException
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.dispatchKeyEvent(IInputMethodSession.java:277)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.dispatchKeyEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1344)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRoot.java:2426)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1741)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Here is the code I have when overriding the back button

```
if(mInputView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

    if(isInputViewShown()){
        if(output != null){
             if(getCurrentInputConnection() != null){
                       getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(1000, 1000);
                       getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(output.getText(), output.length());
             }
        output.setText("");
    }

    requestHideSelf(0);
    return true;
}else return false;
```

Comment: Is this on a phone or the emulator?

Comment: its from a phone that I am debugging with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a race condition between cancelling the keyboard, and dispatching the keyevent that was generated by pressing the back button. The `DeadObjectException` means that although the object (here the `KeyEvent`) is still in use, its host process (the IME) has died. This invalidates the object and throws the exception.

You can see this in the `KeyEvent` parameters. The key code is 4, which is the value of [`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK).

Different phones probably behave different ways here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7958719/324625) unanswered question is similar). I would guess the exception can be ignored.

Comment: Do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't worked with the softkeyboard before. [`requestHideSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#requestHideSelf(int)) is supposed to leave the process running so this doesn't happen, which is why I think this might be phone/implementation specific. If it doesn't crash your program, I would just ignore it. If it does, then maybe you can trap the exception.

Comment: Or you could also try always returning true, even if the input view is not visible. Maybe then the event will be considered handled and won't be used later.

Answer (score 2):

A google search for "android.os.DeadobjectException IME" yields this: http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-10/msg04248.html

It seems that the exception is thrown when the UI hasn't had a chance to process all the key events before the IME is killed. That would explain the first line:

```
12-19 13:18:13.908: W/InputMethodManager(361): IME died: com.mypackage/.MyActivity dropping: KeyEvent{action=1 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=72}
```

This message isn't a big deal, its the result of killing the IME before dealing with all the key events.